# .htaccess remove www with GCP hosted site

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have a website hosted on GCP bucket and I use cloudflare for HTTPS.
How can I use .htaccess file to remove www. from all website pages and redirect them to HTTPS?

Basically, I want:

```
http://www.example.com/ redirect to https://example.com/
https://www.example.com/ redirect to https://example.com/

and any other pages like
https://www.example.com/about.html or http://www.example.com/about.html redirect to https://example.com/about.html
```

I found the configuration for the .htaccess file that I need to add to the root directory of my website:

**Catch all and redirect www to no-www (HTTPS):**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

I replaced example.com with my domain name, put the file into the root directory of my GCP bucket and nothing happened. If I try to access my website by http://example.com I get `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error. I tried to save .htaccess with ANSI and with UTF-8 with the same result.

How do I:

1. Remove www. from my website using .htaccess
2. Redirect users to https:// without www.
3. What encoding should I use for .htaccess? Does it matter?

Is this even possible with my GCP bucket hosted static website and cloudflare provided https://?

I tried setting up redirects through my domain registrar's control panel, but they don't support redirects with dns nameservers other than their own default ones.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use CloudFlare to take care of HTTPS and the www site redirection.

To force HTTPS, go to CloudFlare settings: `SSL/TLS` => `Edge Certificates` => `Always Use HTTPS` => `On`.

> **Always Use HTTPS**:
>   Redirect all requests with scheme "http" to "https". This applies to
>   all http requests to the zone.

To redirect some locations to some other locations, you can create a page rule. See example https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-Configuring-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare-Page-Rules

Comment: When I add a page rule either "mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com" or "www.mydomain.com to "mydomain.com" it doesn't seem to work. mydomain.com is not available, which is because CNAME points to www.mydomain.com, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There could be further issues at play here (It has been a while since I've messed with Apache), but the unescaped periods in your regex for the condition will definitely cause issues. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```